# Chrome - how do I actually VIEW a https certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

While Chrome is happy to show me certificates when they are *invalid*, with a nice warning message, I've just tried to view a certificate for a *valid* site and found there's no obvious way to do so.

If you click the **'Secure'** button in the url bar it shows you the current options for all the various access a site can request, and tells you the communications is secured with https and a link to a google page explaining what this is, but doesn't actually show you any details about the site!

How do you view the cert manually, within Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> if you are on Mac) to open the Developer Tools.

Click on the *Security* Tab and you'll see a Security Overview with a **View Certificate** Button.
[image]